# How to reduce the space in between Streamlit's mutlple buttons

Tags: streamlit

```
col1,col2,col3,col4 = b.columns([1,1,1,1])
with col1:
   st.button("first")
with col2:
   st.button("prev")
with col3:
    st.button("next")
with col4:
    st.button("last")
```

I would like to add reduce some space in between the buttons since they are far.

Any advice?

Thank you

I have tried to use the add extra column space such as

```
col1,_,col2,_,col3,_,col4 = b.columns(8)
```

But it reduce little bit and not responsive well.

Answer (score 0):

The gap between the column can be adjusted by the parameter gap, where the default is the "small", can be "medium" and "large".

```
col1,col2,col3,col4 = st.columns([1,1,1,1], gap='small')
```

The other method that you can do is to adjust the relative width of the column. Second column is 2 times longer, etc.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4 = st.columns([1,2,3,4], gap='small')
```

To compress to the left you can add an extra column that is not used.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 = st.columns([1,1,1,1,4], gap='small')
```

You can also use a float or decimal such as [1, 1.5, 0.5, 0.7].

Reference:
[streamlit columns](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.columns)